# What's the best way to return multiple values in a promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, return

I do realise that when returning a non-promise in a .then() handler, it is immediately passed on to the next handler, if it's a promise that is returned, executing is halted for the promise to resolve before it is passed on to the next handler.

Also I know that only one value can be returned from a promise.

**That beeing said**, how would I go about returning multiple parameters from one .then() handler to the next one? Esepcailly if it's a mix of promises and non-promises. Currently I put everything into a custom object, return it, and use async await in the following then() handler for the promises to reslolve.

Then is use the resolved promise values and the non-promise value to do some work together.

This works fine but my gut is saying that this is somehow not the way it is supposed to be... maybe?

Example:

```
const current = 'blah';
const previous = 'blubb';

this.doSomeAsyncWork()
.then(
    result => {
        const nonPromiseValue = new domSomethingSynchronous(current, previous);
        // "custom object, mix of promises and non-promises"
        return {
            nonPromise: nonPromise,
            promiseA: ControllerA.asyncOperationA(current, nonPromiseValue.someProperty),
            promiseB: ControllerB.asyncOperationB(nonPromiseValue.someOtherProperty),
        }
    }
)
.then(
    async x => {
        const nonPromiseValue = x.nonPromiseValue;
        const valueA = await x.promiseA;
        const valueB = await x.promiseB;

        // do something with the results of those three variables

    }
)
.catch(
    // ...
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `return Promise.all` on the array of Promises and non-Promises at the end of a `.then`, and then you can destructure the results immediately in the next `.then`, no `await` nor `async` needed.

The `Promise.all` will resolve once all `Promises` in the array have resolved. The non-Promises passed to it will just be passed to the next `.then`.

```js
const makeProm = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'resolveValue'));

Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    const prom = makeProm();
    const otherValue = 'foo';
    return Promise.all([prom, otherValue]);
  })
  .then(([resolveValue, otherValue]) => {
    console.log(resolveValue, otherValue);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. Will each element in the array of Promise.all([]) keep its index? If I have e.g. 3 promises [prom1, prom2, prom3, nonProm] and prom3 resolves before prom1, will prom3 still have index 2?

Comment: Yes, each item's respective index will be preserved. Index 1 in the array passed to `Promise.all` will be the same item (or the Promise that resolves to) index 1 in the next `.then`'s array